# Python: How to prevent subprocesses from receiving CTRL-C / Control-C / SIGINT

Tags: python, subprocess, signals, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I am currently working on a wrapper for a dedicated server running in the shell. The wrapper spawns the server process via subprocess and observes and reacts to its output.

The dedicated server must be explicitly given a command to shut down gracefully. Thus, CTRL-C must not reach the server process.

If I capture the KeyboardInterrupt exception or overwrite the SIGINT-handler in python, the server process still receives the CTRL-C and stops immediately.

So my question is:
How to prevent subprocesses from receiving CTRL-C / Control-C / SIGINT?

Comment: I'm interested in the workaround, would be nice if you posted it!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: The dedicated server is running on a Linux system (Debian).

Comment: Does anybody know of a solution for this on *Windows*?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Somebody in the #python IRC-Channel (Freenode) helped me by pointing out the *preexec_fn* parameter of **subprocess.Popen(...)**:

> If *preexec_fn* is set to a callable
>   object, this object will be called in
>   the child process just before the
>   child is executed. (Unix only)

Thus, the following code solves the problem (UNIX only):

```py
import subprocess
import signal

def preexec_function():
    # Ignore the SIGINT signal by setting the handler to the standard
    # signal handler SIG_IGN.
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

my_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["my_executable"],
    preexec_fn = preexec_function
)
```

**Note:** The signal is actually not prevented from reaching the subprocess. Instead, the *preexec_fn* above overwrites the signal's default handler so that the signal is ignored. Thus, this solution *may* not work if the subprocess overwrites the *SIGINT* handler again.

**Another note:** This solution works for all sorts of subprocesses, i.e. it is not restricted to subprocesses written in Python, too. For example the dedicated server I am writing my wrapper for is in fact written in Java.

Comment: `Popen(preexec_fn=...)` [will eventually cause a deadlock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036bb7365607ab7e5cf901f1ac4256f9ae1be82c/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#L932-L938) if used in a python application with multiple threads. I have hit this a few times, and it's documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 27):

Combining some of the other answers that will do the trick - no signal sent to main app will be forwarded to the subprocess.

On Python 3.11 and newer you can use the `process_group` argument for `Popen`:

```
from subprocess import Popen

Popen('do_not_want_signals', process_group=0)
```

On Python 3.10 and older you can use `preexec_fn`:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

def preexec(): # Don't forward signals.
    os.setpgrp()

Popen('do_not_want_signals', preexec_fn=preexec)
# The above can be shortened to:
Popen('do_not_want_signals', preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

Comment: +1 You don't need the `preexec` function, `Popen(args, preexec_nf=os.setpgrp)` is cool too.

Comment: preexec_nf? Better try `Popen(args, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)` ;-)

Comment: On Python 3.11+ get rid of `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` in favor of `process_group=0` as preexec_fn is incompatible with threads. On earlier Python versions you can set `start_new_session=True` and achieve a similar result rather than that `preexec_fn=`, though it's `setsid()` call also does more...

Answer (score 10):

you can do something like this to make it work in windows and unix:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def pre_exec():
    # To ignore CTRL+C signal in the new process
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx
    # If CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flag is specified, CTRL+C signals will be disabled
    my_sub_process=subprocess.Popen(["executable"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
else:
    my_sub_process=subprocess.Popen(["executable"], preexec_fn=pre_exec)
```

Comment: When I use your `creationflags`, the main process is unkillable with Ctrl+C on windows. Ideas?

Comment: @Fuzzyma i found a quick workaround for this by using `win32api` instead of signal: `win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(exit_handler, True)`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: similar note as on the other answer, avoid `preexec_fn=` and use 3.11's `process_group=0` or 3.2's `start_new_session=True` flags as `preexec_fn=` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 5):

After an hour of various attempts, this works for me:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["someprocess"], creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

It's solution for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting SIGINT to be *ignored* before spawning the subprocess (reset it to default behavior afterward).

If that doesn't work, you'll need to read up on [job control](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) and learn how to put a process in its own background process group, so that <kbd>^C</kbd> doesn't even cause the kernel to send the signal to it in the first place.  (May not be possible in Python without writing C helpers.)

See also [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232613/how-to-stop-sigint-being-passed-to-subprocess-in-python).

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work (ignoring SIGINT *before* spawning the subprocess, i.e. not the job control thing). I have a workaround for now, which I will present later today or tomorrow.