# How NOT to kill a subprocess Popen when typing ctrl-c

Tags: python

I've see many posts where ctrl-c supposedly kills a subprocess.

However I have the opposite problem. In my code I have following line:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", script_file])
```

Now when I type ctrl-C randomly in Python console, this subprocess will exit. I **dont't** want this to happen. Is there a way to make sure it doesn't happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to prevent subprocesses from receiving CTRL-C / Control-C / SIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045771/python-how-to-prevent-subprocesses-from-receiving-ctrl-c-control-c-sigint)

Comment: One option is to run this process as a service. How that is done depends on the OS.