How do I ensure that my Python script and its child processes handle Ctrl-C properly?
System:

A Raspberry Pi-4 running Buster using Python 3.7 with an Adafruit 128x32 2.23" OLED Bonnet connected to the GPIO pins.  Ref: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-23-monochrome-oled-bonnet

The original version of the script I am using can be found at: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-23-monochrome-oled-bonnet/usage#verify-i2c-device-3064554


Issue:
When running a Python program via a terminal window, CTL-C doesn't always produce the orderly shutdown I want to happen.  When run inside of Thonny, it appears to always work.

Note the following Python script which was lifted verbatim from Adafruit's web site to test their 128x32 OLED Raspberry Pi "Bonnet".
I modified it by adding some code to capture and handle signal interrupts such that it would clear and close the display when the program ends.
Viz.:
#!/usr/bin/python3.7

# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: <text> 2020 Tony DiCola, James DeVito,
# and 2020 Melissa LeBlanc-Williams, for Adafruit Industries </text>

# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


# This example is for use on (Linux) computers that are using CPython with
# Adafruit Blinka to support CircuitPython libraries. CircuitPython does
# not support PIL/pillow (python imaging library)!

# Modified 2024/10/12 by Jim Harris to allow for signal capture
# and a graceful shutdown

import os
import signal
import sys
from threading import Condition, Thread, Event
import time
import subprocess
from board import SCL, SDA, D4
import busio
import digitalio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import adafruit_ssd1305

# check if it's ran with Python3
assert sys.version_info[0:1] == (3,)

# for triggering the shutdown procedure when a signal is detected
keyboard_trigger = Event()
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('\nSignal detected. Stopping threads.')
    keyboard_trigger.set()

# registering both types of signals
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

# Get PID of this running script
pid = os.getpid()

# Define the Reset Pin
oled_reset = digitalio.DigitalInOut(D4)

# Create the I2C interface.
i2c = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)

# Create the SSD1305 OLED class.
# The first two parameters are the pixel width and pixel height.  Change these
# to the right size for your display!
disp = adafruit_ssd1305.SSD1305_I2C(128, 32, i2c, reset=oled_reset)

# Clear display.
disp.fill(0)
disp.show()

# Create blank image for drawing.
# Make sure to create image with mode '1' for 1-bit color.
width = disp.width
height = disp.height
image = Image.new("1", (width, height))

# Get drawing object to draw on image.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
draw.rectangle((0, 0, width, height), outline=0, fill=0)

# Draw some shapes.
# First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
padding = -2
top = padding
bottom = height - padding
# Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
x = 0


# Load default font.
#font = ImageFont.load_default()

# Alternatively load a TTF font.  Make sure the .ttf font file is in the
# same directory as the python script!
# Some other nice fonts to try: http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf', 9)
print("Started system statistics printout as PID", pid)

# Main drawing routine
#while True:
while not keyboard_trigger.is_set():
    # Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, width, height), outline=0, fill=0)

    # Shell scripts for system monitoring from here:
    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/command-to-display-memory-usage-disk-usage-and-cpu-load
    cmd = "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1"
    IP = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"CPU Load: %.2f\", $(NF-2)}'"
    CPU = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = "free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf \"Mem: %s/%s MB  %.2f%%\", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'"
    MemUsage = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}\''
    Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")

    # Write four lines of text.

    draw.text((x, top + 0), "IP: " + IP, font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top + 8), CPU, font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top + 16), MemUsage, font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top + 25), Disk, font=font, fill=255)

    # Display image.
    disp.image(image)
    disp.show()
    time.sleep(0.1)

# until some keyboard event is detected
print("\nA keyboard event was detected.")
print("Clearing and shutting down display")

# Clear display.
disp.fill(0)
disp.show()
sys.exit(0)

Case 1:  Run from within Thonny
Running from within Thonny always produces the following output within Thonny's terminal (REPL) window.
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %cd /home/pi/startup_scripts
>>> %Run Stats.py
Started system statistics printout as PID 24225

Signal detected. Stopping threads.

A keyboard event was detected.
Clearing and shutting down display

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> 

Each and every time, the script responds to a CTL-C with a clean shutdown and clearing the display, which is the desired and expected behavior.
Case 2: Running within a terminal window.
When run within a terminal, I get the following:
Try 1:  Sending an explicit kill signal from another terminal window:
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $ ./Stats.py
Started system statistics printout as PID 15893

Signal detected. Stopping threads.

A keyboard event was detected.
Clearing and shutting down display
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $

This has happened every single time I've "Killed" the process via another terminal.
Try 2:  Killing within the running terminal window using CTL-C
Attempt 1:
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $ ./Stats.py
Started system statistics printout as PID 16921
^C
Signal detected. Stopping threads.

A keyboard event was detected.
Clearing and shutting down display
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $

Attempt 2:
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $ ./Stats.py
Started system statistics printout as PID 17587
^C
Signal detected. Stopping threads.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Stats.py", line 104, in <module>
    Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}'' died with <Signals.SIGINT: 2>.
pi@Adafruit128x32:~/startup_scripts $ 

Here I got an unhandled exception thrown, and this is the most common outcome. (the try where it worked was actually a suprise to me.)
What I suspect is happening is that there are other bits of library code running that catch the CTL-C keyboard signal, and the "bits of library code" aren't passing the exception "up the ladder" to the process where I am handling the error.
Question:

Why is this happening?

Is there a way to ensure that my code captures the keyboard signal so that it can shutdown cleanly without the messy unhandled exception that usually happens?



This feels like an XY problem that could be easily solved with the psutil module instead of using subprocesses.

Stats.py forks new processes, which are added to the current process group.
When you send SIGINT to Stats.py, the other processes don't receive that signal at all.
When you use Control-C, the terminal delivers SIGINT to every process in the current process group. Your code isn't prepared for them to be stopped by some external signal; it assumes that they will run to completion unless interrupted by Stats.py itself. Whether you get the error depends on exactly when you press Control-C, and whether any given subprocess is executing that time.
As far as I know, you cannot change the signal handlers for the subprocesses; you only only react to how they do handle SIGINT, or (and I'm not sure how exactly to go about this) ensure that they run in a separate process group from the one your script executes in. (This doesn't mean they will react differently to SIGINT, but does ensure that when you press Control-C, the terminal doesn't send SIGINT to them.)

Chepner and @Dunes: Ok, I get it. Stats.py starts child processes and they are essentially independent of the parent process. Since this is   probably a common thing, how do I coordinate all these processes so they all shut down gracefully?  Links to relevant articles would be appreciated.

Your child processes are picking up the signals that have been sent to the whole process group (ie. Ctrl-C), and not just your python parent process. They are exiting early, and then python is raising this as an error.
There is a way to get the child processes to ignore certain signals from the parent python process. But it's not especially pretty and there is a small potential for the python process to miss some signals.
What you can do is, tell your current process to ignore the signals that you want the child process to ignore. You then start your child process, whilst telling python not to restore these ignored signals. Finally, you then switch your old handlers back on.
import signal
import subprocess

def my_check_output(args, shell=False):
    original_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            args,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            restore_signals=False,
            shell=shell,
        )
    finally:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_handler)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        return out, err
    else:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
            proc.returncode, args, out, err
        )


Where does this fit into the existing code?

It's a drop-in replacement for subprocess.check_output

What happens to the child processes when the parent terminates?  Do they automagically get killed too, or do I have to go kill them explicitly?

The parent process cannot manually terminate whilst it is waiting for the custom check output to finish. If the parent process recieves a sigint, it is processed per your handler. If a sigterm is received then both parent and child process it with their default handlers and start terminating. There are caveats to this, such running the code in a daemon thread, or any other scenario where the interpreter might stop abruptly.

Thanks! I appreciate your help.  I don't know if you got notified of my @ mention of you below, if you didn't please go look.  In essence I am sure that I'm not the first person to run into this (:wink:) and I am equally sure there is a lot of good information out there - though finding it is like searching for a needle in the Mojave desert!  Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

I didn't see the @, I think because you added a : directly to the end of my handle. I had a look, and I'm starting to think this is an XY problem. Are you doing anything other than querying stats about the system?

I don't even think this is a good solution any more. I think you should catch the CalledProcessError, and if keyboard_trigger has been set, then just ignore the exception and exit the loop. That is, if you don't go the psutil route, which I think is the best solution.

@Dunes may I suggest it'd be safer/correct to SIG_IGNore SIGINT only in the child processes, by using the preexec_fn argument to subprocess.Popen.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045771/python-how-to-prevent-subprocesses-from-receiving-ctrl-c-control-c-sigint.  I am going to try it

@pilcrow I note that using preexec_fn forces subprocess to use fork instead of spawn to create child processes. Which means you cannot use threads, or use libraries that use native threads. That's not to say that the above code is thread safe though. I believe multiprocessing prefers spawn over fork for this reason too. I think I see a solution that temporarily blocks the signal what would be safe, and preserves the use of spawn over fork.

@Dunes that's fair.  How about adding set_start_method('spawn')?
