# Run a program from python, and have it continue to run after the script is killed

Tags: python, subprocess, nohup

I've tried running things like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'my_command'],
                 stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                 stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'))
```

This works if the parent script exits gracefully, but if I kill the script (Ctrl-C), all my child processes are killed too. Is there a way to avoid this?

The platforms I care about are OS X and Linux, using Python 2.6 *and* Python 2.7.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The usual way to do this on Unix systems is to fork and exit if you're the parent. Have a look at `os.fork()` .

Here's a function that does the job:

```
def spawnDaemon(func):
    # do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced 
    # Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            # parent process, return and keep running
            return
    except OSError, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, "fork #1 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
        sys.exit(1)

    os.setsid()

    # do second fork
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            # exit from second parent
            sys.exit(0) 
    except OSError, e: 
        print >>sys.stderr, "fork #2 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
        sys.exit(1)

    # do stuff
    func()

    # all done
    os._exit(os.EX_OK)
```

Comment: If I fork, and then I kill one half of the fork (rather than allowing it to exit), will that kill the new process?

Comment: Okay, after further reading: this requires forking twice to avoid receiving signals? I'd quite like the parent process to remain interactive --- its job is to monitor the processes that it spawns --- which isn't possible if it has to disown the shell.

Comment: Thanks! I've added my implementation to your answer.

Comment: This is great as it sets the daemon **parent process ID** to 1 so that it's completely disconnected from the parent. The subprocess command I ran from the other answer was killed by my Torque job scheduler, even when changing its process group because the parent process ID still matched the dying process.

Comment: In this implementation an intermediate child is left as a zombie until parent exists. You need to collect its return code in the parent process to avoid that, e.g. by calling `os.waitid(os.P_PID, pid, os.WEXITED)` (before returning in the main process)

Comment: Is there any way to communicate the PID of that child process to the parent thread? Even if its through locks/delays? Of course I could print it with os.getpid() but that doesn't mean the parent that spawned it can know that PID.

Answer (score 66):

The child process receives the same `SIGINT` as your parent process because it's in the same process group. You can put the child in its own process group by calling `os.setpgrp()` in the child process. `Popen`'s `preexec_fn` argument is useful here:

```
subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'my_command'],
                 stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                 stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'),
                 preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
                 )
```

(`preexec_fn` is for un*x-oids only. There appears to be a rough equivalent for Windows "`creationflags=CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`", but I've never tried it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it works for me! However, I am curious why my command stops (process dies) after some point, if I omit the `stdout` & `stderr` agruments.

Comment: maybe the stdout and stderr buffers fill up and the process becomes deadlocked?

Comment: If you are using `shell=True` then `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is probably what you want

Comment: Is `nohup` needed if you call `setpgrp`? Wouldn't the latter prevent the child from getting `SIGHUP` from the parent, as it is no longer part of the same process group?

Comment: It's not clear to me when these `open`'s are closed -- if at all. To me, this is at least implicit behavior and I would bundle them with `with` as written [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514518/3383640).

Answer (score 16):

After an hour of various attempts, this works for me:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["someprocess"], creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

It's solution for windows.

Comment: This works on Windows in 2021. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since 3.2 you can also use `start_new_session` flag (POSIX only).

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "60"], start_new_session=True)
ret = p.wait()
```

See [start_new_session in Popen constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: Yes, but note that the parent process of p still is the calling process. And of course the OP does not want to `p.wait()`. And if p fails and it still has the calling process as its parent, then it will become a zombie process.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make the subprocess ignore SIGINT.

```py
import subprocess
import signal
subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "100"], preexec_fn=lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN))
```

Using `preexec_fn` ensures that the parent process's SIGINT handler is not changed. (if it's changed you need to restore it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22916783/5267751).)

Of course, this will only work if the subprocess does not proceed to reinstate the signal handler. In the following case where the subprocess installs a signal handler, the subprocess would still be killed:

```py
import subprocess
import signal
process=subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", "import signal\nimport time\nsignal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)\nwhile True: \n    print(1)\n    time.sleep(1)"], preexec_fn=lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN))
process.wait()
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731948/5267751 .

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('/dev/null', 'w') as stdout, open('logfile.log', 'a') as stderr:
    subprocess.Popen(['my', 'command'], stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
```

> **class subprocess.Popen(...)**
>
> Execute a child program in a new process.
>   On POSIX, the class uses os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the
>   child program. On Windows, the class uses the Windows CreateProcess()
>   function.
>
> **os.execvpe(file, args, env)**
>
> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current
>   process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded
>   into the current process, and will have the same process id as the
>   caller. Errors will be reported as OSError exceptions.