# python 2.3 - remove directory without waiting for process to finish

Tags: python, linux, python-2.3

I wish to write a python script (to be run in Linux) that one of its requirements is to remove a directory.
the problem is that the directory is very big and takes minutes to complete.

Problems:

1. I don't want the remove command to block script execution
2. most importantly I want the remove command to allow the script to finish its execution and keep working even after the script is terminated

is it doable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille and try that in Python 2.3...

Comment: Thank you. should have searched better.
hope that'll do the trick.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to search if you don't know the key words!

Comment: Agree. I always post a question as a last resort. this time I gave in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that would satisfy those requirements would be a daemon. Fork and then return from the main process. That way the remove call can block as much as it likes.

```
doRemove()
   fork()
   if child
      call huge remove
   else
      return
```