# How to let the child process live when parent process exited?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use `multiprocessing` module to complete this.

when I do this, like:

```
    $ python my_process.py
```

I start a parent process, and then let the parent process spawn a child process,

then i want that the parent process exits itself, but the child process continues to work.

Allow me write a **WRONG** code to explain myself:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(x):
    with open('out.dat', 'w') as f:
        f.write(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bbb',))
    p.daemon = True    # This is key, set the daemon, then parent exits itself
    p.start()

    #p.join()    # This is WRONG code, just want to exlain what I mean.
    # the child processes will be killed, when father exit
```

So, how do i start a process that will not be killed when the parent process finishes?

---

20140714

Hi, you guys

My friend just told me a solution...

I just think...

Anyway, just let u see:

```
import os
os.system('python your_app.py&')    # SEE!? the & !!
```

this does work!!

Comment: No, a daemonic process will be killed when it's parent process exit. "When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes." from https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon

Comment: Why would you let your child processes live without a parent? With no parent they will become zombies.

Comment: @Pphoenix, not really. Zombies are child processes that have exited but whose parents still haven't waited for. Orphaned processes are adopted by `init` and keep going on.

Comment: @WKPlus Yes, you are right... I just found this in my test... The task in child do not do...

Comment: @Pphoenix As you know, every process have a father process, As @Frédéric Hamidi said, father process exited, child process' father become `init` process.

Comment: Did not think of that, thank you both for clarifying!

Comment: @WKPlus do you have some solution??

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something like `nohup` or `os.fork`. A similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille

Comment: @Dunes Greet thanks~ Let me have a look~

Comment: @Dunes I just read the link, does it mean `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` can not do this? But, linux os programming is a perfect solution.

Comment: A trick: call `os._exit` to make parent process exit, in this way daemonic child processes will not be killed.

Comment: @k9x You're really not supposed to use the `multiprocessing` module like this. It's meant to be used as a drop-in replacement for threads, which of course cannot live beyond the life of the parent process. If you want to spawn a process that can live beyond the life of the parent, use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @k9x See this answer for a cross-platform way of properly launching a de-coupled child process using `subprocess`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/2073595

Comment: @dano Big thanks, `subprocess.Popen()` did NOT block the father process, father process just exited, let child finish. U should answer this~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A trick: call `os._exit` to make parent process exit, in this way daemonic child processes will not be killed.

But there are some other side affects, described in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit):

```
Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, 
flushing stdio buffers, etc.
```

If you do not care about this, you can use it.

Comment: what if you double fork? so parent spawns child1 that spawns your daemon. then child1 calls os._exit, and parent is free to do a clean exit

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to achieve an independent child process that does not exit when `__main__` exits. It uses the `os._exit()` tip mentioned above by @WKPlus.

[Is there a way to detach matplotlib plots so that the computation can continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue/56982302#56982302)