# Popen, multiprocessing and daemons with Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, popen, python-multiprocessing

I need to run a long *foobar.py* process with **Popen** and parse its output with a **multiprocessing** process.

My problem is that sometimes I cannot wait for the parser to finish, so I need to daemonize the parser using [the multiprocessing daemon property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon). I need the parser to be usable both deamonic non daemonic ways. The doc also says that *a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes*. So in that case I run the Popen process before the parser is forked (see the start method below).

```py
class Parser(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, daemon, output):
        super(Parser, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.output = output

    def start(self):
        if self.daemon:
            self.launchFoobar() # Foobar is launched before forking
        super(Parser, self).start()

    def run(self):
        if not self.daemon:
            self.launchFoobar() # Foobar is launched after forking
        self.parseFoobar()

    def launchFoobar(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "foobar.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    def parseFoobar(self):
        with open(self.output, "w+") as f:
            for line in iter(self.process.stdout):
                f.write(line)
                f.flush()
        self.process.wait()
```

Let's say here that [foobar.py](https://gist.github.com/azmeuk/78731ba1aa00f6fd53d7) just waits some seconds and print something, and *parseFoobar* method just prints output in a file. In my case both functions are a lot more complex than this.

Running `Parser(daemon=False, "sync.txt").start()` works fine and there is some output in *sync.txt*. But running `Parser(daemon=True, "async.txt")` does not produce anything in *async.txt* and seem to be blocked at line `for line in iter(self.process.stdout):` because the file is created, but it is empty.

Why doesn't it work? How can I fix it?

You can find gists for [parser.py](https://gist.github.com/azmeuk/838fe2bf5380c5de4efa) and [foobar.py](https://gist.github.com/azmeuk/78731ba1aa00f6fd53d7) for testing. Just run `python parser.py` and look at output files.

Edit: There are some tips in [django daemonize methods](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/daemonize.py#L9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually getting the exact behavior you want. You're creating a daemon `Process`, and then almost immediately exiting the main process. That doesn't give the daemon `Process` enough time to actually execute `foobar.py` and parse its output before it gets terminated. If you add a call to `async.join()` at the end of the program, you'll see that `async.txt` does get written.

Also note that you *can* call `subprocess.Popen` from inside the daemon `multiprocessing.Process`. That note about `daemon` processes not being able to create subprocesses is actually just talking about creating child `multiprocessing.Process` objects. The limitation is there because the daemon `Process` won't be able to properly clean up child `Process` objects, but processes opened by `subprocess.Popen` don't get cleaned up when the parent exits, anyway.

Comment: What is the point of creating a daemon process if you call join() at the end? In this very case I need to create the process and just forget it. It is very likely that the parser die after its parent.

Comment: @azmeuk That's fine, then you can do that. But then sometimes the daemon `Process` isn't going to do the work you expect it to. In this case, the parent is exiting before the daemon `Process` can parse the output of `foobar.py`.

Comment: @azmeuk I would say that in general it's actually dangerous to have a daemon `Process` write to a file, because the file could easily end up in a corrupted state if the daemon is abruptly terminated in the middle of writing to it.

Comment: The principle of a daemon process is that it can survive its parent, am I wrong? In that case how can it abruptly terminate?

Comment: @azmeuk No, daemon `multiprocessing.Process` objects are **terminated** as soon as the parent process exits. They don't live beyond the parent's lifetime. `multiprocesing.Process` is meant to be very similar to `threading.Thread`; a daemon `Thread` can't live beyond the life of its parent process, so neither does a `multiprocessing.Process`.

Comment: I see. [It seems that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694763/how-to-let-the-child-process-live-when-parent-process-exited) ```os._exit``` can be used for children to survive parents though.

Comment: @azmeuk Yes, just note that no cleanup of the parent whatsoever is done when you use that. I actually think that your non-daemon `Process` will live beyond the life of the parent if you use that approach.