# Clear sys.argv in python

Tags: python, argv

When user specify a password in MySQL cli, aka `-pXXXXXX`, the password parameter is replaced to `-p******` in argv array.

So when someone check the process list with `ps`, they can't see the password.

How can I do the same in Python? This doesn't work obviously

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    arg = ""
```

Comment: Have you tried `sys.argv = []`. Also `del sys.argv[1]` (or whatever the index of the argument should be), which might just delete the one item?

Comment: @martineau It's more like to override the memory that argv points to

Answer (score 6):

`sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]`

works and is more efficient and elegant than deleting all but the first element. I can't confirm this would overwrite or erase previous value of sys.argv in memory though.

Comment: @lilydjwg What version of python are you using? Should be fine in 2.7 or 3.6. I tested in each and it worked. https://gist.github.com/jtara1/900a580b362ea1c8b3b7019695e04519

Comment: It doesn't change what you see from outside in top / ps / etc. If you pass a password in an argument, it will be visible to other users on the same system (as long as they can see your process).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper that accepts a password and other arguments. It will then spawn a child, pass it the password in the way that's not visible in command line, eg. with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), and kill itself. For killing processes while keeping their children alive look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694763/how-to-let-the-child-process-live-when-parent-process-exited).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way so I turn to environment variables for tokens (and unset it once acquired to prevent leaking to child processes).