# Limiting the number of processes running at a time from a Python script

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm running a backup script that launches child processes to perform backups by rsync.  However I have no way to limit the number of rsyncs it launches at a time.

Here's the code I'm working on at the moment:

```
print "active_children: ", multiprocessing.active_children()
print "active_children len: ", len(multiprocessing.active_children())
while len(multiprocessing.active_children()) > 49:
   sleep(2)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_backup, args=(shash["NAME"],ip,shash["buTYPE"], ))
jobs.append(p)
p.start()
```

This is showing a maximum of one child when I have hundreds of rsyncs running.  Here's the code that actually launches the rsync (from inside the do_backup function), with `command` being a variable containing the rsync line:

```
print command
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
return 1
```

If I add a sleep(x) to the do_backup function it will show up as an active child while it's sleeping.  Also the process table is showing the rsync processes as having a PPID of 1.  I'm assuming from this that the rsync splits off and is no longer a child of python which allows my child process to die so I can't count it anymore.  Does anyone know how to keep the python child alive and being counted until the rsync is complete?

Comment: Have yo considered using a process pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clear up some misconceptions first

> I'm assuming from this that the rsync splits off and is no longer a
>   child of python which allows my child process to die so I can't count
>   it anymore.

`rsync` does "split off". On UNIX systems, this is called a [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29).

When a process forks, a *child process* is created - so `rsync` **is** a child of python. This child executes independently of the parent - and concurrently ("at the same time").

A process *can* manage its own children. There are specific [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for that, but it's a bit off-topic when talking about python, which has its own high-level interfaces

If you check [`subprocess.Popen`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), you'll notice that it's not a function call at all: it's a class. By calling it, you'll create a instance of that class - a [Popen object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).
Such objects have multiple methods. In particular, [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) will allow you to [block](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-what%27s-the-difference-between-a-blocking-and-a-non-blocking-call-793677/) your parent process (python) until the child process terminates.

---

With this in mind, let's take a look at your code and simplify it a bit:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_backup, ...)
```

Here, you're actually forking and creating a child process. **This process is another python interpreter** (as with all `multiprocessing` processes), and will execute the `do_backup` function.

```
def do_backup()
    subprocess.Popen("rsync ...", ...)
```

Here, you are forking **again**. You'll create yet another process (`rsync`), and let it run "in the background", because you're not `wait`ing for it.

---

With all this cleared up, I hope you can see a way forward with your existing code. If you want to reduce it's complexity, I recommend you check and adapt JoErNanO's answer, that reuses `multiprocessing.Pool` to automate keeping track of the processes.

Whichever way you decide to pursuit, you should avoid forking with `Popen` to create the `rsync` process - as that creates *yet another process* unnecessarily. Instead, check `os.execv`, which **replaces** the current process with another

Comment: Thanks, appending .wait() to the Popen that launches rsync fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

## Multiprocessing Pool's

Have you thought about using [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)'s? These allow you to define a fixed number of worker processes which are used to carry out the jobs you want. The key here is in the *fixed number* which will give you full control over how many instances of rsync you will be launching.

Looking at the example provided in the documentation I linked, first you declare a `Pool` of `n` processes, and then you can decide if to `map()` or `apply()` (with their respective `_async()` siblings) your job to the pool.

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    pool.apply_async(f, (10,))    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    ...
    pool.map(f, range(10))
```

The obvious advantage here is that you will never unexpectedly fork-bomb your machine as you will spawn only the requested `n` processes.

## Running Your rsync

Your process spawning code would then become something like:

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool

def do_backup(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...):
    # Do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start a Pool with 4 processes
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    jobs = []

    for ... :
        # Run the function
        proc = pool.apply_async(func=do_backup, args=(shash["NAME"],ip,shash["buTYPE"], ))
        jobs.append(proc)

    # Wait for jobs to complete before exiting
    while(not all([p.ready() for p in jobs])):
        time.sleep(5)

    # Safely terminate the pool
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: You're missing the bit of magic that'll allow him to actually run a non-python-interpreter process (such as `rsync`): `os.execv` or similar

Comment: @goncalopp I'm assuming that bit of code already exists in the OP's `do_backup()` function. :)

Comment: Your answer is more Pythonic than mine +1

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes, of course - but it's the `do_backup` he's having trouble with in the first place! :) As it stands, if you applied your code to his `do_backup`, it'd probably lead to the exact same behaviour he's getting - note that he's not calling `wait`, so the subprocesses in the `Pool` would return immediately while `rsync` is still running.

Comment: @goncalopp Ah OK i get it now. Basically as his code stands he is forking twice: once for `Popen` and once for `rsync`. So `Popen` will exit while `rsync` is still running. Let me mull this over.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to mention that doing another `POpen` (as opposed to `execv`) will duplicate the number of processes unnecessarily.

Comment: This worked for keeping a count on child processes, but Popen doesn't like to run when I used a pool.  Not sure why, I may look into it later.  Adding .wait() per goncalopp's reply fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not multithreading, but multiprocessing. I'm assuming you're on a Unix system, if you're using `rsync` although I do believe it can run on Windows systems.  In order to control the death of spawned child processes, you must `fork` them.

There's a good question about doing it in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille).

Comment: Note `subprocess.Popen` is doing the fork in his code. `fork`ing is very low level, and uncommon in python code - there are higher level libraries that help in this kind of tasks (such as `multiprocessing`, as mentioned by JoErNanO)