# Launch modules as subprocesses in the background, and detach

Tags: python, subprocess, detach

In `bash`, I can do the following:

```
for f in subdir/*.sh; do
    nohup "$f" "$@" &> /dev/null &
done
```

in other words, it runs all `*.sh` scripts in `subdir` in the background, and detached so that if the main script ends, the background scripts won't be terminated.

Now, let's say I have the following Python project:

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    subdir/
        __init__.py
        mod_a.py
        mod_b.py
        mod_c.py
```

How do I do something similar to the bash script? But with parameters passed as Python objects?

E.g.: I have two strings `a` and `b`, a list `l`, and a dictionary `d`

- Load `mod_a.py`, invoke `mod_a.main(a, b, l, d)`, and detach
- Load `mod_b.py`, invoke `mod_b.main(a, b, l, d)`, and detach
- Load `mod_c.py`, invoke `mod_c.main(a, b, l, d)`, and detach
- `main.py` can end, letting `mod_a`, `mod_b`, and `mod_c` run in the background until completion

Answer (score 1):

To emulate `nohup` in Python, you could make child processes to ignore `SIGHUP` signal:

```
import signal

def ignore_sighup():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

i.e., to emulate the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in subdir/*.sh; do
    nohup "$f" "$@" &> /dev/null &
done
```

using `subprocess` module in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from glob import glob
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL, STDOUT

for path in glob('subdir/*.sh'):
    Popen([path] + sys.argv[1:], 
          stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT, preexec_fn=ignore_sighup)
```

To create proper daemons, you could use [`python-daemon` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any mechanism for it in python, but you may try to use `nohup`. You may try to run

```
nohup python your_script.py arguments
```

Using `os.system` or `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a duplicate of [Run a program from python, and have it continue to run after the script is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille) and no, ignoring SIGHUP doesn't help, but preexec_fn=os.setpgrp does.

Comment: [`nohup`](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/nohup/nohup.c.html) does not create a new process group. `preexec_fn=os.setsid` is not enough to create a completely detached subprocess too. See [correct daemon behaviour](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour).