# Run program in another process and receive pid in Python

Tags: python, unix, process, subprocess

I want to run a program in another process, get pid this program and child process should be not depended from parent. Please see following Python code:

```
cmd = 'myPythonProgramm -p param'
pid = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True).pid
```

But if I kill parent process then also kill child process. 
This issue is not exist if I use:

```
os.system('nohup myPythonProgramm -p param &')
```

But in this case I can't get child process pid. 
**How can I run a program in another process, get pid this program and child process should be not depended from parent?**

Comment: here's how to [emulate `nohup` utility in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27549535/4279)

Comment: J.F. Sebastian thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into Unix process group management. In particular, when you kill the session leader of a process group when it is attached to a terminal (as is your script), all processes in that group receive a `SIGHUP`, which by default causes termination.

One solution is to establish a new session for the child using `os.setsid()`. In Python 3 `subprocess.Popen()` accepts a `start_new_session=True` which does this for you. For Python 2, we can get a similar solution using `preexec_fn`:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```