# nohup: failed to run command

Tags: python, linux, debian

For some strange reason when i run a python script with:

`subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "openvpn --config '/usr/local/etc/openvpn/pia_openvpn/AU Melbourne.ovpn'"])`

I get

`nohup: failed to run command ‘openvpn --config '/usr/local/etc/openvpn/pia_openvpn/AU Melbourne.ovpn'’: No such file or directory`

I can run `openvpn --config "/usr/local/etc/openvpn/pia_openvpn/AU Melbourne.ovpn"` with no errors. I've also tried running other commands and get the exact same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a program from python, and have it continue to run after the script is killed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011235/run-a-program-from-python-and-have-it-continue-to-run-after-the-script-is-kille)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave `nohup` one single argument containing spaces and quotes, and it failed to find a command with that name. Split it so the command is `openvpn`, with two more arguments (you'll probably find the extra quotes around the last argument shouldn't be there either). Sometimes this job is left to a shell, as with the `system` function, but that is in general riskier (similar to SQL injection) and inefficient (running another process for a trivial task).