# pywinauto possible to keep application alive if I exit python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start("program.exe")
```

I am using `pywinauto` to do some tasks indefinitely.  However, occasionally, I need to restart the script for some external reasons.   When this happens, I would like to keep the created applications open.  How can I do this? I noticed if the python script errors out, the applications will stay open.  But if I exit the script manually, the windows will close.  So there must be some way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pywinauto`'s `Application.start` cannot do the work. You can try:

```
pid = os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "program.exe")
app = Application().connect(process=pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.spawnl` is considered deprecated. Use `subprocess` module.

Combining the answer in [Run a program from python, and have it continue to run after the script is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63208428/4661625) and [pywinauto official doc](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=subprocess#entry-points-for-automation), you can do this:

```py
subprocess.Popen(
    ['your_program', 'with args'],
    # These will make sure the desktop program will alive even when shell session terminates.
    creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, shell=True
)
desktop = Desktop(backend="uia")
main_win = desktop.window(title="program's window title", control_type="Window")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use system command:

```
#Use multiple thread to avoid block of system function 
import _thread as qd 
import os
qd.start_new_thread(os.system,('notepad',))

from pywinauto import Application
#connect pywinauto with application via title regular expression
win=Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re='.*Notepad.*')
```

Then you use pywinauto to connect application via title?